# Error with SQLConn class

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

"SQLConn().Open()" is flagging up an error "Class 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' cannot be indexed because it has no default property." I am very confused by this as I have used the exact same syntax in other (working) files. Advice appreciated. Thanks

```
Using SQLConn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DataConnectionRemoteSQL").ConnectionString)


            Try
                SQLConn().Open()

                Using cmd = New SqlCommand()
                    cmd.Connection = SQLConn
                    cmd.CommandText = "Select_UserLoginData"
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    param1 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usern", username_s)
                    param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                    param1.DbType = DbType.String


                    Using user_rs = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                        If user_rs.Read() Then


                            'Create hash of plain text password entered 
                            hashedpassword_s = s_CreateHash(password_s, user_rs("Salt"))

                            'If this password doesn't match what's stored in the database
                            If Not hashedpassword_s = user_rs("Hashed") Then
                                lbl_ErrorPanelText.Text = "Incorrect login credentials!"
                                pn_ErrorPanel.Visible = True

                            Else
                                Session("check") = 1
                                user_rs.Close()
                                Response.Redirect("menu.aspx", False)
                            End If

                        Else
                            lbl_ErrorPanelText.Text = "Incorrect login credentials!"
                            pn_ErrorPanel.Visible = True
                        End If

                    End Using

                End Using


            Catch ex As Exception

                lbl_ErrorPanelText.Text = "Error establishing a database connection!"
                pn_ErrorPanel.Visible = True

            End Try
        End Using
```

Answer (score 4):

You have an unnecessary set of empty brackets following `SQLConn`. Change to `SQLConn.Open()` and this particular problem will go away.

Generally brackets following a local variable denote "default property"/indexer access (i.e. accessing elements in an array by their numeric index), hence the error message.